# Read makernote EXIF tag in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to decode the Makenotes Exif Tag using C#

Below returns the Makernote Tag, but I have no idea how to **decode the makenotes data**

```
//MakerNotes 37500
    public byte[] GetMakerNotes()
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyItem propItem = image.GetPropertyItem(37500);
            byte[] pv0 = propItem.Value;

            return pv0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.GetType().ToString() != "System.ArgumentNullException")
            {
            }
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

With my test image, the above returns a byte array 7632 bytes long.

I am not sure if the makenotes tag info has some sort of sub-tag which can be used?

These links indicate something like this:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Canon.html

I looked at the JEITA CP-3451 spec to see how tags are constucted, but the bytes returned from the makernotes tag dont seem to follow this.

http://www.kodak.com/global/plugins/acrobat/en/service/digCam/exifStandard2.pdf

Entire byte array as read without any sort of byte decoding as follows:

```
 byte[] notes = r.GetMakerNotes();
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.Length; i++)
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText(notes[i].ToString() + "\n");
        }
```

39  0   1   0   3   0   49  0   0   0   104 5   0   0   2   0   3   0   4   0   0   0   202 5   0   0   3   0   3   0   4   0   0   0   210 5   0   0   4   0   3   0   34  0   0   0   218 5   0   0   6   0   2   0   15  0   0   0   30  6   0   0   7   0   2   0   24  0   0   0   62  6   0   0   9   0   2   0   32  0   0   0   86  6   0   0   13  0   7   0   0   6   0   0   118 6   0   0   16  0   4   0   1   0   0   0   1   3   0   128 19  0   3   0   4   0   0   0   118 12  0   0   25  0   3   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   38  0   3   0   139 0   0   0   126 12  0   0   53  0   4   0   4   0   0   0   148 13  0   0   147 0   3   0   32  0   0   0   164 13  0   0   149 0   2   0   74  0   0   0   228 13  0   0   150 0   2   0   16  0   0   0   46  14  0   0   151 0   7   0   0   4   0   0   62  14  0   0   152 0   3   0   4   0   0   0   62  18  0   0   153 0   4   0   38  0   0   0   70  18  0   0   154 0   4   0   5   0   0   0   222 18  0   0   160 0   3   0   14  0   0   0   242 18  0   0   170 0   3   0   6   0   0   0   14  19  0   0   180 0   3   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   208 0   4   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   224 0   3   0   17  0   0   0   26  19  0   0   1   64  3   0   32  5   0   0   60  19  0   0   8   64  3   0   3   0   0   0   124 29  0   0   9   64  3   0   3   0   0   0   130 29  0   0   16  64  2   0   32  0   0   0   136 29  0   0   17  64  7   0   252 0   0   0   168 29  0   0   18  64  2   0   32  0   0   0   164 30  0   0   19  64  4   0   11  0   0   0   196 30  0   0   21  64  7   0   196 1   0   0   240 30  0   0   22  64  4   0   7   0   0   0   180 32  0   0   24  64  4   0   7   0   0   0   208 32  0   0   25  64  7   0   30  0   0   0   236 32  0   0   32  64  4   0   5   0   0   0   10  33  0   0   37  64  4   0   9   0   0   0   30  33  0   0   39  64  4   0   5   0   0   0   66  33  0   0   0   0   0   0   98  0   2   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 127 255 127 3   0   2   0   0   0   3   0   255 255 53  0   55  0   18  0   1   0   148 0   64  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 255 255 255 255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 255 255 0   0   0   0   255 127 255 255 255 255 255 255 0   0   255 255 0   0   42  0   111 247 10  85  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   68  0   0   0   192 0   232 0   148 0   20  1   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   8   0   8   0   148 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   148 0   20  1   146 0   0   0   0   0   248 0   255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0   0   0   0   0   0   67  97  110 111 110 32  69  79  83  32  54  53  48  68  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   70  105 114 109 119 97  114 101 32  86  101 114 115 105 111 110 32  49  46  48  46  52  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   170 170 125 45  125 45  80  0   1   182 1   182 0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   6   0   0   0   148 146 0   125 0   130 0   131 0   42  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   1   187 187 0   32  255 231 0   128 250 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   161 0   0   255 23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  157 40  122 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   182 0   113 4   12  31  0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 255 255 12  204 204 2   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   80  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   80  20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   135 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   144 179 145 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   45  88  0   53  0   18  0   55  145 101 146 63  0   255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   22  179 48  0   0   0   2   45  0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   64  20  0   0   128 13  0   0   30  9   0   0   104 5   0   0   4   2   0   0   176 2   0   0   208 2   0   0   224 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   208 2   0   0   224 1   0   0   208 2   0   0   224 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   208 2   0   0   224 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 255 127 255 255 255 127 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  2   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   49  46  48  46  52  0   56  55  40  50  56  41  0   22  106 0   12  0   0   0   128 71  73  0   24  2   152 25  88  254 19  0   188 203 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   142 0   0   0   100 0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   174 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   0   0   101 0   0   0   100 0   0   0   8   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   227 1   0   4   0   4   148 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   227 1   0   4   0   4   148 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   227 1   0   4   0   4   148 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   227 1   0   4   0   4   148 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   227 1   0   4   0   4   148 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   239 190 173 222 239 190 173 222 0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   135 0   135 0   135 0   0   0   255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   43  79  71  84  30  2   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   184 52  0   0   244 55  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   83  0   0   0   88  0   3   128 0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   77  0   0   0   78  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   51  0   0   0   59  0   3   128 0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   84  0   0   0   89  0   3   128 0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   87  0   0   0   94  0   3   128 0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   88  0   0   0   95  0   0   0   0   0   159 0   7   0   112 0   22  1   2   0   31  0   9   0   64  20  128 13  64  20  128 13  129 0   129 0   129 0   181 0   222 0   181 0   129 0   129 0   129 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   172 0   172 0   172 0   117 0   224 0   117 0   172 0   172 0   172 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   168 250 205 252 205 252 0   0   0   0   0   0   51  3   51  3   88  5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   131 1   125 254 251 2   0   0   5   253 131 1   125 254 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 16  0   0   0   120 0   0   0   18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   64  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 255 255 125 0   255 255 0   0   0   0   182 0   113 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 0   0   12  0   31  0   255 255 255 255 69  70  45  83  49  56  45  53  53  109 109 32  102 47  51  46  53  45  53  46  54  32  73  73  73  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   186 147 144 191 68  65  49  56  57  57  50  55  48  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   152 0   0   0   4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   32  0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   20  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   3   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   32  0   0   0   2   0   0   0   14  5   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   15  6   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   44  0   0   0   3   0   0   0   1   7   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   7   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  8   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   64  20  0   0   128 13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   28  0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   255 255 80  20  135 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   12  0   69  2   0   4   0   4   79  2   0   0   34  0   160 20  200 13  1   0   1   0   84  0   64  0   147 20  191 13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   16  3   0   4   0   4   119 1   37  2   0   4   0   4   245 1   129 1   0   4   0   4   202 2   247 5   234 7   237 7   229 2   124 6   25  12  30  12  217 5   80  3   191 8   191 8   243 5   5   0   0   0   13  1   9   1   16  1   0   0   27  6   84  13  76  13  179 7   157 2   207 0   208 0   30  0   141 0   58  3   55  3   227 4   175 5   208 9   208 9   191 1   40  6   86  13  85  13  162 7   158 2   232 0   231 0   34  0   143 0   56  3   57  3   176 4   181 5   204 9   212 9   211 1   6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   88  16  0   4   0   4   0   4   0   4   88  16  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  6   9   0   4   0   4   201 5   112 23  3   9   255 3   0   4   200 5   112 23  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  217 9   0   4   0   4   109 5   88  27  37  9   0   4   0   4   218 5   112 23  29  6   0   4   0   4   123 9   128 12  104 7   0   4   0   4   246 8   136 14  132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  123 9   0   4   0   4   203 5   138 24  132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  132 8   0   4   0   4   90  6   80  20  61  4   0   4   0   4   38  4   184 16  61  4   0   4   0   4   38  4   184 16  61  4   0   4   0   4   38  4   184 16  61  4   0   4   0   4   38  4   184 16  61  4   0   4   0   4   38  4   184 16  182 254 102 1   124 3   148 42  199 254 111 1   103 3   16  39  244 254 133 1   47  3   108 32  41  255 160 1   243 2   88  27  94  255 192 1   188 2   112 23  121 255 207 1   162 2   224 21  150 255 225 1   133 2   80  20  198 255 252 1   86  2   92  18  254 255 34  2   38  2   104 16  51  0   74  2   253 1   216 14  97  0   111 2   217 1   172 13  155 0   158 2   176 1   128 12  198 0   195 2   145 1   184 11  243 0   246 2   124 1   240 10  101 1   122 3   66  1   96  9   244 1   17  8   33  8   0   8   0   8   0   8   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   4   0   27  0   6   0   20  0   39  0   152 0   68  2   18  3   56  2   145 1   115 0   14  0   31  0   0   0   23  0   154 0   13  7   224 39  254 0   80  2   244 3   224 11  211 37  96  21  227 12  192 6   152 2   90  1   221 2   9   0   116 0   245 3   221 28  89  81  23  1   129 1   146 2   140 1   170 7   86  4   208 2   181 2   249 0   209 0   49  1   18  0   41  4   210 23  121 91  214 172 85  7   233 11  34  9   34  10  218 25  112 10  143 10  85  9   163 4   86  3   171 4   50  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   128 0   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   201 10  80  15  98  26  208 14  80  255 241 255 33  15  73  17  201 0   17  0   237 16  0   0   0   1   1   0   158 250 3   0   22  139 3   0   217 132 2   0   1   0   0   4   0   4   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   253 255 0   0   255 31  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   4   165 2   179 1   227 1   148 2   142 1   56  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   31  0   63  0   95  0   127 0   159 0   191 0   223 0   255 0   0   0   44  0   93  0   130 0   158 0   181 0   203 0   227 0   255 0   1   0   0   0   98  0   0   0   16  0   32  0   64  0   96  0   128 0   192 0   0   0   137 255 150 255 150 255 150 255 148 255 0   0   136 4   155 4   150 4   150 4   150 4   153 4   202 3   136 4   1   0   255 7   255 7   0   8   0   8   244 56  244 58  16  39  0   0   213 0   111 0   56  0   1   0   90  0   210 6   70  7   144 13  16  14  178 5   38  6   144 13  16  14  66  6   182 6   144 13  16  14  102 0   96  0   84  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   57  65  0   0   32  0   64  0   128 0   224 0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   46  0   94  0   159 0   228 0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   95  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   17  0   52  0   103 0   154 0   255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   27  0   54  0   125 0   209 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   110 5   0   4   83  3   109 2   0   4   0   4   62  2   50  0   74  0   140 125 127 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   238 1   78  0   0   0   149 2   98  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   169 2   0   4   0   4   185 1   100 0   0   0   64  0   63  0   238 128 158 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   85  0   80  0   62  0   49  0   39  0   255 0   69  84  225 123 5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   44  0   93  0   130 0   158 0   181 0   203 0   227 0   255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   34  0   69  0   101 0   132 0   162 0   192 0   223 0   255 0   216 0   223 0   225 0   219 0   184 0   130 0   84  0   61  0   57  0   59  0   66  0   74  0   90  0   114 0   132 0   158 0   191 0   218 0   245 0   253 0   252 0   246 0   237 0   228 0   221 0   210 0   190 0   182 0   181 0   186 0   191 0   194 0   191 0   181 0   170 0   159 0   157 0   161 0   161 0   154 0   141 0   132 0   122 0   117 0   114 0   96  0   83  0   67  0   58  0   54  0   49  0   47  0   45  0   44  0   47  0   51  0   59  0   64  0   71  0   76  0   75  0   73  0   63  0   0   0   255 0   5   0   85  0   80  0   69  84  225 123 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   39  0   255 0   49  0   54  4   232 0   0   0   25  1   28  0   0   0   64  1   0   0   1   0   62  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   0   0   168 170 0   0   104 6   140 60  16  19  0   0   0   0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   40  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   85  0   80  0   69  84  225 123 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   39  0   255 0   49  0   238 128 158 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   69  84  225 123 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   31  0   63  0   95  0   127 0   159 0   191 0   223 0   255 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   135 0   135 0   135 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   44  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   255 255 255 255 0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  0   0   0   0   32  196 1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   66  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   204 16  64  20  128 13  255 31  61  28  6   25  115 21  33  20  8   18  0   0   178 3   234 5   34  8   223 8   26  10  0   64  38  64  62  64  63  64  40  64  27  64  0   64  95  64  151 64  249 64  98  65  142 65  0   0   178 3   234 5   34  8   157 9   26  10  217 63  213 63  209 63  213 63  226 63  233 63  0   0   178 3   234 5   34  8   157 9   26  10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   28  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   28  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   22  179 48  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   36  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   20  0   0   0   4   6   5   0   40  0   0   135 0   0   0   7   48  48  48  0   73  73  42  0   142 3   0   0

Comment: What was the manufacturer of the camera was used for this image? The method to parse MakerNotes will vary between each camera manufacturer. You would have to reverse engineer each possible format if you plan to receive images from a various sources.

Comment: For the time being I'd be happy to just decode Canon (Model EOS 650D). The tags between models from the same manufacturer also seem to differ

Comment: Can you post the entire byte array?

Answer (score -1):

It's a propriary data blob. It's described [here](http://lclevy.free.fr/cr2/) for the Canon 450D.

The first bytes in your byte array does not, however, seem to correspond to something sane according to the linked document. Either there are some other data before that you need to strip, or the 650D has some additional format ids not documented in the link above.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm not getting is that makernotes is Tag 37500. Then in the description of the MakerNotes, they again start from Tag 0 or Tag 1?